# opengl glTranslatef() cant get more than one in my code

Tags: opengl

i have to make 4 rectangles all in the middle and transform them to different
locations.
with this all my glrects get the first translate i have also pushMatrix but nothing.
Help me please

```
  #include <GL\glut.h>
     void display() {
     glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                       glLineWidth(3);

                          glColor3f(0,0,1);
 glBegin(GL_LINES);
         glVertex2f(0,-24);
            glVertex2f(0,24);

             glVertex2f(-32,0);
             glVertex2f(32,0);
           glEnd();


      glTranslatef(-32,-14,0);
      glColor3f(1,0,0);
     glRecti(0,0,20,10);



 glTranslatef(10,5,0);
     glColor3f(0,1,0);
     glRecti(0,0,20,10);

glFlush();
  }
  int main(int argc, char** argv){
     glutInit(&argc,argv);
     glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
     glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
     glutCreateWindow("Example");
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     gluOrtho2D(-32,32,-24,24);
     glutDisplayFunc(display);
     glutMainLoop();
     return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you let GL_PROJECTION active:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(-32,32,-24,24);
```

After that you have to make modelview active:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: when i set the translate to the second glrect it works fine...
but then i set and the first one and the second one also moves.
but know it moves from the place where i say in its gltranslate.
i need them to move individualy

Comment: the only way to work like this is to add the x,y of every previus glTranslate to every new one